# Notation for domain and range of a function

Tags: functions, notation

Suppose function $f$ and sets $X$ and $Y$ such that $f : X \rightarrow Y$.

What does this notation exactly mean, out of the following options?

- $\text{domain(} f) \subseteq X \wedge \text{range(} f) \subseteq Y$
- $\text{domain(} f) = X \wedge \text{range(} f) \subseteq Y$
- $\text{domain(} f) = X \wedge \text{range(} f) = Y$

For example look at these three statements for the real-valued square root:

- $\sqrt{x} : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
- $\sqrt{x} : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$
- $\sqrt{x} : \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$

which one of them are correct?

Comment: "What does this notation exactly mean, out of the following options?" domain(f)=X∧range(f)⊆Y is.    The notation $f:X \to Y$ means that every element of $X$ is mapped from so $X = domain(f)$.  And it means that all the elements of $X$ are mapped into $Y$ so $range(f)\subseteq Y$.  But it does not mean all elements of $Y$ have to be mapped to; just that the elements of $X$ can't be mapped *outside* $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the notation $f: X \rightarrow Y$, $X$ is the domain of $f$ and $Y$ is the codomain. The range of $f$, which we sometimes write as $f(X)$, is a subset of $Y$.

So then for the square root function, both $\sqrt{}: \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\sqrt{}: \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ are valid, but $\sqrt{}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is not because the function is not defined on negative numbers. There is also a related function $\sqrt{}: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which only takes inputs in the natural numbers, but note that we couldn't define $\sqrt{}: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ because then there would be inputs that don't produce a valid output.